# How to import an MEF class in AssemblyInitialize

Tags: c#, mef, composition

```
  [TestClass]
    public static class AssemblyTests
    {
        private static IDisposable _composerWrapper;

        [Import]
        private static IReportTestEnvironmentSetup _reportTestEnvironmentSetup;

        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void Initialize(TestContext context)
        {
            AssemblyTests._composerWrapper = Composer.Load();
            TeamFoundationTestConfig.UpdateTfsReportServerInCommonConfig();
            _reportTestEnvironmentSetup.ServiceWarmUp(TeamFoundationTestConfig.ReportingServiceBaseUrl);
            _reportTestEnvironmentSetup.ServiceWarmUp(TeamFoundationTestConfig.SsrsWarmUpUrl.InvariantFormat(TeamFoundationTestConfig.TFSReportServer));
        }

        [AssemblyCleanup]
        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            AssemblyTests._composerWrapper.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

How do i import  `IReportTestEnvirommentSetup` in assembly initialize. This class currently gives me a warning that that the property is never assigned. I do this in all other test class and it works fine because `AssemblyTests._composerWrapper = Composer.Load();` sets up a composition scope for the current application.

Can someone help me correct my mistake?

Comment: Found solution myself

Comment: public static void Initialize(TestContext context)
        {
            AssemblyTests._composerWrapper = Composer.Load();  IReportTestEnvironmentSetup reportTestEnvironmentSetup = Composer.Current.GetComponent<IReportTestEnvironmentSetup>();
            reportTestEnvironmentSetup.ServiceWarmUp(TeamFoundationTestConfig.SsrsWarmUpUrl.InvariantFormat(TeamFoundationTestConfig.TFSReportServer)); }